# Mocking of Where method in Data Repository is returning null at its actual implementation in repository

Tags: asp.net, testing, null, moq, xunit

I have written a test for edit model of a class in EF core.

```
public async Task<Expense> EditExpense(Expense model)
{
        var expense = _dataRepository.Where<Expense>(x => x.Id == model.Id).ToList();

        if(expense != null)
        {
            expense.ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.Name = model.Name;
                x.AddedOn = model.AddedOn;
                x.Amount = model.Amount;
                x.Type = model.Type;
                x.SplitOption = model.SplitOption;
                x.Notes = model.Notes;
                x.IsGroupExpense = model.IsGroupExpense;
            });

            return expense.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

I want to test this method using xUnit and Moq and I have also written a method for it as below.

```
[Fact]
public async void UnitTest_IsExpenseEdited_ReturnsTrue()
{
        var expenseCurrent = new Expense()
        {
            Id = 5,
            Name = "Test Expense",
            Amount = 1500,
            AddedBy = "44db32c3-ad6a-4d68-a683-862be363f59c",
            AddedOn = DateTime.Now,
            Notes = "",
            IsDeleted = false,
            IsGroupExpense = false,
            SplitOption = 1,
            Type = 0
        };

        var expenseList = (new List<Expense>{ expenseCurrent });

        var expenseAfterEdit = new Expense()
        {
            Id = 5,
            Name = "Test Expense Edited",
            Amount = 2000,
            AddedBy = "44db32c3-ad6a-4d68-a683-862be363f59c",
            AddedOn = DateTime.Now,
            Notes = "Edited !!!",
            IsDeleted = false,
            IsGroupExpense = true,
            SplitOption = 2,
            Type = 0
        };

        _dataRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Where<Expense>(a => a.Id == expenseCurrent.Id)).Returns(expenseList as IQueryable<Expense>);

        var expenseEdited = await _exepenseRepository.EditExpense(expenseAfterEdit);
        Assert.Equal(expenseEdited, expenseAfterEdit);
}
```

But here, the `Where` method is returning null

```
public async Task<Expense> EditExpense(Expense model)
{
        var expense = _dataRepository.Where<Expense>(x => x.Id == model.Id).ToList(); in repository 
}
```

I am getting var expense null in above code.

Please suggest what should I include in the code to get the value in above var expense?

To test this method, I want to create a fake data which is going to be updated. Please suggest how this thing needs to be written properly?

Comment: Show the definition of the `Where` member

Comment: I am afraid the setup of the `_dataRepositoryMock.Where` is not correct but it cannot be answered without the `Where` method signature...

Comment: this is the definition of where method...

    `public IQueryable<T> Where<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate) where T : class
        {
            DbSet<T> _table = GetDbSet<T>();
            return _table.Where(predicate);
        }`

Comment: Could you try to setup repository like this: `_dataRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Where<Expense>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Expense, bool>>>())).Returns<Expression<Func<Expense, bool>>>(e => expenseList.Where(e.Compile()).ToList());`

Comment: Done. Its working now. Thanks !!